# Microsoft Designer Mouse makes worse WiFi on ASUS UX31A laptop with Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, mouse, bluetooth, asus, 15.10

This bluetooth mouse doesn't work out of box, but I found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/698356/472223) how to make it work. After this a cursor is moved, even though mouse's type is still "any device". So, it works, but I found a strange side effect: when the mouse is on, the my wifi connection is very slow. I made plot of [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70sN8.png) to a my wifi-router to demonstrate a affects with on/off the mouse. When the mouse is off, ping ~1 ms, but when mouse is on, ping ~20k(!) ms. 
My system is ASUS UX31a laptop with Ubuntu 15.10 and I haven't a Windows or other laptops with bluetooth 4.0 to test if the effect exists on other systems. So I can't say it is a bug of Ubuntu or hardware (ux31a have a WLAN and BT4.0 on the one plate, may be it is important).

Comment: Check to see if there is a Bluetooth coexist modprobe option for your WiFi module. If so, enable it.

Comment: Also, your router may also have a bt coexist settings as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works with iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 and bt_coex_active=0  options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a following file with the settings to force using wifi g (11n_disable) and disable coexisting (bt_coex_active):

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf (file to be created)
-------------------------------------------------
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Seems, necessity to disable coexisting is to says about a bug, see [here](https://superuser.com/a/924560).

Comment: Yeah, I guess it depends on the module, some work better with coexist enabled, some don't.