# Cursor jumps ahead

Tags: mouse, cursor

I have had endless problems with graphic rendering on my computer. I think I have fixed most of these issues, but one annoyance is that my cursor often jumps ahead.

This is different than similar problems I see on this site, where the mouse drags behind, or jumps when someone's hand grazes the touchpad. In my case, I will move my cursor along and then, all of the sudden, it will anticipate the direction I'm going and then overshoot, missing the target.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I have an obscure notebook called an MSI Slidebook. It has an integrated Intel GPU.

Comment: What Ubuntu release do you got?  Could you paste `lshw -C video` output?

Comment: 16.0.3. lshw output is here: https://pastebin.com/vWFPMZjb

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is related to the Bluetooth mouse. When I use a USB wireless mouse it's fine. When I use a Microsoft Designer bluetooth mouse, it jumps when pages are loading, or other processes are going on.

Comment: Type `xinput list` at terminal (with connected bluetooth mouse) and post output here, we could search for any issues about this device.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/im8rzRAb ("Designer Mouse" is the mouse)

Comment: Fine. Post `xinput list-props 14` now. Adding: Did you see [this page talking about your mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694503/how-do-i-use-a-microsoft-designer-mouse-with-ubuntu-15-10)?

Comment: list-props 14: https://pastebin.com/CmuUtEF9 . As for the link, I have had similar problems to those listed there, and have fixed them. But those fixes don't address the jumpiness.

Comment: I think if you disable Device Acceleration you solve this issue. According to [this page](https://gist.github.com/martynjarvis/6d9eb738c2ab83bf33ab), you could try to `xinput set-prop 'Designer Mouse' 266 -1` and `xinput set-prop 'Designer Mouse' 267 1.000`

Comment: The first command, 266 -1, fixes the problem. I tried to make this persistent by adding the command to my startup applications, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Redbob had the answer that worked for me:

```
xinput set-prop 'Designer Mouse' 266 -1
```

I should mention that it isn't persistent for me, though.

Comment: So my suggestion is to create a script with this command and enable it as autostart script.